# What's the structure of an XBee signal in transparent mode?

Tags: signal, embedded, communication, xbee

I can't find this one anywhere. Does it only contain the message which needs to be transmitted? Does it also contain some address headers of the source and destination modules?

Comment: web  says...When operating in transparent mode, an XBee module acts as a serial line replacement. All data received through the serial input is immediately transmitted over the air. When the XBee module receives wireless data, it is sent out through the serial interface exactly at it is received.

Comment: It contains overhead which gets removed so you do not see it.